# Sharing data between application and helper processes in macOS / iOS

Tags: swift, macos, ios-app-group

I've learnt that it's possible to share configuration data (like registry in Windows) between different components if those components share a similar appGroup entitlement.

In my scenario I've got multi user application run as launchAgent and root-mode process run as launchDaemon that I want to share the same configuration source (each process may read/write from/to the shared configuration source).

However, when using the proper API to access this data from the application, I see that it's backed by file inside app owner home folder :

```
(lldb) po FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.bla.bla")
▿ Optional<URL>
  ▿ some : file:///Users/myUser/Library/Group%20Containers/group.com.bla.bla/
    - _url : file:///Users/myUser/Library/Group%20Containers/group.com.bla.bla/
```

So my question in this case is how to share the configuration data between multi user processes that each have the same appGroup entitlement ?

thanks